# Can composite primary keys be used to prevent you from linking unrelated objects?

Tags: database-design, primary-key, composite-key, composite-primary-key

If I have a couple models in (name your favorite framework):

```
# pseudo-code
class Fruit
    primary_key = CompositeKey(tenant_id, object_id)
    weight = DecimalField()

class Restaurant
    primary_key = CompositeKey(tenant_id, object_id)
    haz_cheeseburger = BooleanField()
    fruit_available = ForeignKey(Fruit)  # <-- important part
```

Is it possible to have a database constraint that will make it impossible to insert a `Resaturant` who's `tenant_id` part of the primary key points to `TenantA` and who's `fruit_available`'s `tenant_id` points to `TenantB`. Basically, protect me from accidentally relating objects that belong to different tenants.

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood you correctly, you might be able to set a foreign key. In the restaurant table,

```
FOREIGN KEY        (tenant_id, fruit_available) 
  REFERENCES fruit (tenant_id, fruit_available)
```

It depends in part on your dbms, and in part on whether there's a unique constraint of any kind on `fruit (tenant_id, fruit_available)`.

That won't prevent you from using the wrong tenant_id as part of Restaurant's primary key, though.

Comment: What I'm wondering is whether I can prevent myself (via a constraint) from ever linking a `Restaurant` with `TenantA` as the `tenant_id` and link it to a `Fruit` that has `TenantB` as the `tenant_id`.

Comment: @orokusaki: Did you try my answer? What happened?

Comment: I don't actually have the ability to use a composite key in my current code, which is why I'm asking in an abstract way vs giving actual code examples, etc. I'm curious, because Django has been working toward (slowly) getting composite PKs into the core framework.

Comment: @orokusaki: Of course you can use a composite key in your current code, at least for testing. Open your development database's SQL utility, and key in the `ALTER TABLE` statement to create the foreign key. Then try to enter valid data, and try to enter invalid data. Doesn't matter what ORM you're using, you can always go straight to the database for testing.